# What is the command to find display details of an iOS device?

Tags: ios, shell, command, display

I am trying to find display details of an iOS device like resolution, pixels, xdpi, etc. but could not find any ideviceinfo command. Please let me know if there are any commands to find this.

Answer (score 0):

there is no iOS device info command for iOS devices. However, you still have a few options to find what you are looking for. I suggest the ActMonitor app this available in App Store, but many others can do the job. Here is a link with a few of them: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/iphone-ipad-screen-resolution/